# Why am I not able to expand my hard drive partition after deleting Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, partition

I'm a MacBook user and I had previously installed Windows on my laptop.

After deleting the Windows partition now, I'm facing difficulty in expanding my hard drive partition to the maximum. After I drag the the partition to *Full* and click *Apply*, it shows:

> Checking journaled HFS+ volume

Then, a message pops out:

> Partition failed with the error : couldn't modify partition map because file system verification failed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Reboot the Mac into Single User Mode by holding ⌘ (Command) + S when pressing the power button.
2. When the command prompt finally appears, type:
    `/sbin/fsck - fy`
3. After this is completed, type `reboot` or `exit`.
4. Wait for Mac to start up normally.
5. Back in Disk Utility, hit `Verify Disk`, then try and partition as normal.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1417 says that "If you're using Mac OS X 10.4 or later, you should use Disk Utility instead of fsck, whenever possible".

Answer (score 1):

Simply Hold Shift before startup. This brings the mac into safe mode and it checks the system for errors. Then try modifying the partition again.

Comment: It just verifies or repairs the startup volume (the partition like `Macintosh HD`), which can also be done from Disk Utility.

Comment: Disk utility is UNABLE to repair the volume because it's the startup volume. Going into safe mode checks and Repairs any errors on the drive as well

Comment: Disk Utility does allow repairing the startup volume if you start up from a recovery partition or installation disk. When I tried [starting up in safe mode with verbose mode enabled](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92266/understanding-how-safe-boot-fixed-a-boot-problem/92315#92315), it only seemed to check the Macintosh HD volume and not the drive.